# Passing dictionary key and values to a function

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries.  Each dictionary has a set of numerical keys, and a list of values to go with them, three in total, symmetrical data structures:

```
   dict_list = {key1: [1,2,3],
                key2: [4,5,6],
                ...}
```

I'm using

```
    def function(dict_list):
     converted_dict_list = []
     for i in range(0,4):
        new_dict = {k:map(external_function,value) for k, value in dict_list[i].iteritems()}
     return converted_dict_list
```

This goes through each list for each key in each dictionary.  Sends them to an `external_function` for processing and updates in a new list of dictionaries.

But I want to send both the values *and* the key for each value (as floats) to an external function; the result bounced back from the external function will only be used to update value (same as the example given). They keys are strings but do contain a now-needed float or integer value.

Comment: So... what's the *problem*?

Comment: Are you looking for the `float` builtin ?

Comment: Problem is map only takes one function parameter.  But I need to implement the above code to send two.  The extra parameter is the key of a dictionary  for example '5.5'...So in the structure I gave, 'key1' and say '1' both need to go to the external function at the same time.

Comment: Have you considered using `functools.partial` or a `lambda` expression to create something you can use with `map`? Alternatively, switching to a list comprehension might be better: `{k: [external_function(float(k), val) for val in value] for...}`.

Comment: `map` can accept any number of iterables after the function parameter. The function thus need to accept as much parameters as the number of iterables. So what you need is a way to convert your float-containing string into an iterable that has the same size than the list of values. Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pull the keys and values from a dict you can use

```
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
```

Then just type jungle the float out of the string.

```
new_float = float(key)
```